# IIS 10 CA Root Certificate is not trusted

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-10

I have successfully installed the SSL and I also installed the Trusted Root Certification in the the Trusted Root Certifications Store.

Yet it is still saying to install it in the trusted root store.

https://www.k-9styles.com/

I am using a Rapid SSL RSA SSL

Comment: Are you aware that as a Self Signed cert no matter what you do that's not going to work for a general website on the public internet?  If you are and this is for testing what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using a Rapid SSL RSA SSL is it appearing as a self signed cert?

Comment: Yep - Issued by "K-9 Styles" - did you update the IIS bindings?

Comment: I selected the uploaded SSL from IIS in the bindings. Do you have a guide I could follow. I will unistall and reinstall everything.

Comment: You can do it all through IIS: https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO29632.html

Comment: Everytime I complete the CCR. The SSL appears then disappears when I try to link it.

Comment: could you explain how you configure certificate in iis? this issue uccors when the user had actually downloaded the intermediate certificate and used that .cer file to complete the certificate request. In this case the wizard will go thro’ all the steps but when you refresh the view the certificate will not be listed.